# What can I do with this problem with mysql php and table result?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query to list name categories and avg of each one, but the result is not what I want, how to sove this? if you look to image you see that the table resulta don't show correct

```
$query = $connMysqli->query("SELECT qc.name as cat_name

FROM fhrw_question_categories qc
  ...
group by Quiz, cat
ORDER BY u.id");

?>
<table>
<tr>
<?php
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<th>' . $row['cat_name'] . '</th>';   
}?>
</tr>

<!-- table continiuous avg-->
<?
$query = $connMysqli->query("SELECT avg(IFNULL(fraction, 0)) * 10 as Media, u.ud as student, qc.name as cat_name

FROM fhrw_question_attempt_steps qc
 ...
group by Quiz, u.id, cat
ORDER BY u.id ASC");
?>

<?php
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<tr><td>' . $row['cat_name'] . ' - ' . round($row['Media'],2) . '</td></tr>';
}?>
```

[image]

Comment: You should just do `group by cat_name`

Comment: What is the result supposed to look like?

Comment: Why are you calculating `Media` in the first query if you don't echo it?

Comment: If you want a column for each category, you should use a pivot query. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns

Comment: @Barmar you are right, it is not necessary calculate Media in the first query. it Edited

Comment: Ok, I should use pivot query, but it is very dificult understand it.